# Implementing an graph in python from file

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a graph from a file, while having no issues creating the two classes(Edge, node) or reading from the file, I find it quite hard to implement a loop that creates a certain number of edges and nodes from the file.

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number

class edge(object):
    def __init__(self,source,destination):
        self.source=source
        self.destination=destination

file=open("example.txt","r") 

file.close()

one=node(1)
two=node(2)
three=node(3)
four=node(4)

a=edge(1,2)
b=edge(1,3)
c=edge(1,4)
d=edge(2,1)
e=edge(2,2)
f=edge(3,4)
g=edge(4,2)
```

So I'm Looking for a method that can produce those objects I created by hand in a loop from a file which kinda looks like this:(first nodes, edges, number of nodes, number of edges)

```
1
2
3
4

1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
3 4
4 2

4
7
```

Comment: You need to provide the code that you have tried. How have you attempted the `for` loop you mentioned.

Comment: Unless you are writing this as an exercise I would recommend using graph library that exists, like [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)

class edge(object):
    def __init__(self,source,destination):
        self.source=source
        self.destination=destination
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.source)+" "+str(self.destination)

txt_nodes = [1,2,3,4]
txt_edges = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(3,4),(4,2)]

nodes = {}
for n in txt_nodes:
    nodes[n] = node(n)

edges = []
for (a,b) in txt_edges:
    edges.append(edge(nodes[a], nodes[b]))

for k,v in nodes.items():
    print (v)

for e in edges:
    print (e)

print (len(nodes))
print (len(edges))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of nodes and edges are unknown, you should consider using a list `nodes` and `edges` to store them instead of using single variables like `a`, `b`, `c`.

Here is one of the possible approaches:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number

class edge(object):
    def __init__(self,source,destination):
        self.source=source
        self.destination=destination

nodes = []
edges = []
number_of_nodes = -1
number_of_edges = -1

with open("example.txt", "r") as f:
    # 0 is node input; 1 is edge input; 2 is total number of nodes and edges
    state = 0
    for line in f:
        # remove newline characters
        l = line.split('\n')[0].split('\r')[0]
        # empty line means switching state
        if line == '\n':
            state += 1
            continue
        if state == 0: # nodes input
            nodes.append(node(int(l)))
        elif state == 1: # edges input
            node_ids = l.split(' ')
            edges.append(edge(int(node_ids[0]), int(node_ids[1])))
        elif state == 2: # total nodes and edges input
            if number_of_nodes == -1:
                number_of_nodes = int(l)
            elif number_of_edges == -1:
                number_of_edges = int(l)
```

Comment: The number of nodes and edges aren't unknown, they are simple variables. So there no way to create those objects in my class?

Comment: I meant they are unknown by the time you write the code. If you know that the number of nodes is always 4 then you can use a, b, c, d as variable names. If the number of nodes can vary depending on the `example.txt` file then it is unknown so you can't use a, b, c, d as variable names because there is a possibility that there will be more than 4 nodes so you won't have enough variables to store. List is useful in this situation because it can store an arbitrary number of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file = open("example.txt","r")
contents = file.read().split('\n')

node = True
for line in contents[:-3]:
    if line is '':
        node = False
        continue
    if node:
        node(eval(line))
    else:
        src, dest = line.split()
        edge(eval(src), eval(dest))

file.close()
```

Comment: If you need number of nodes and edges, use `nodes = contents[-2]`   `edges = contents[-1]`